# Anonymous Inner classes inside generics

Tags: java, generics, overriding, anonymous-inner-class

I have created an ArrayList of 'T' :

```
ArrayList<T> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, I want to override how the `T`'s inside this ArrayList are compared (e.g. by using anonymous inner classes).

Is there any way I can do this without creating a subclass of `T`?

Comment: When would they be compared? Your question is unclear. What does a subclass have to do with it?

Comment: I want to override the equals method for the T's for this arraylist only.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: You can provide a custom `Comparator<T>` to use when comparing/sorting/etc. You can't however "include" that *with* the List if it's going to be sorted etc by "other" code

Comment: @Bohemian I already have that. But, I want a different comparator for just this ArrayList implementation.

Comment: I suggest creating a subclass of ArrayList for this purpose, having something like a comparing method or overriding the sort method or whatever you would like to use the different comparing for.

Comment: @Grochni won't work for `Collections.sort()`, which doesn't consult the List impl to determine how to compare elements

Comment: You might be able to do this with a [proxy.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)  It's been a while since I've played around with those, and I seem to remember that you need a separate interface, which might sink ya.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just parameterize the ArrayList and then have the objects you put in the list implement the comparable interface?  Maybe I'm missing what you're trying to do here, but it seems like you're over engineering sorting.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html